# Sample Size for Correlation Testing

Tags: statistics, correlation

A research team wishes to test the null hypothesis: $H_0, r=0$ at $\alpha = 0.025$ against the
alternative: $H_1, r>0$ using Fisher’s transformation of the Pearson product moment
correlation coefficient as the test statistic. They have asked their consulting statistician
for a sample size $n$ such that $\beta = 0.05$ when $r= 0.10$ (that is, $r^2 = 0.01$ ). What is this
value?

I used the following equation:

$$n=\frac{Z_{\alpha}+Z_{\beta}}{(0.5\ln(\frac{1+r}{1-r}))}^2+3$$

and got $n\ge1303$, this is different from the answer my professor provided which is $n\ge1320$.

Am I using the correct equation and just plugging in the wrong values or do I have the wrong equation?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! To correctly format equations use dolar signs and greek letters with back slashes eg `$\alpha = \beta$` which renders $\alpha =  \beta$.

Comment: Do you mean expand as in expand out to a series?  If so no I did not try that.

Comment: Still works out to the same value of 1303.  I'm beginning to think it's a typo on the provided solution we were given.

Comment: @chinny84 seems like the answer is correct and it's a difference caused by rounding off.  Thanks for help Chinny.

Comment: Ah the rounding error it sounds like that given the divisor. But great stuff. Write up an answer and accept it to close it off :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation is correct and the result is off due to differences in rounding.  Use the following values for the variables:

Zalpha = 1.96 
Zbeta = 1.645 
r = 0.10